# Create plug-in systemin PHP for API-clients

Tags: plugins, client

I am currently working with the option in my CMS to send messages  with PHP to social media via APIs from a queue in the database.

Consider, for example, Facebook, Twitter/X, BlueSky and Mastodon.

I know you can download various API clients for Composer on Packagist, but now I am curious whether there is a certain system with which you can install such clients as a kind of plugin, so that my sending cron job does not require too much maintenance, and that you can use minimal changes can add a new client.

Of course I am aware of Composer's autoloader, but perhaps implementing this could be easier.

And I also wondered how I can ensure that as soon as a client fails, the rest of the sending clients is carried out as normal.

Anyone with some tips?